# Reprint every other value based on rows from one column to a new one

Tags: r, variables, time, multiple-columns, rows

I am fairly new to using R but I was wondering if there was a way to create a code to reprint the first row of every two rows in a column into a new column. For example, I have a data frame like this:

```
Name    V1  V2  
User1   a   time1
User1   a   time2
User1   b   time3
User1   b   time4
User2   c   time5
User2   c   time6
```

My data frame is essentially divided up by V1 and has two rows for each value. Then V2 has a different time corresponding to each row. I would like to create a new column(V3) that only has the first of the two times and another column (V4) to only has the second of the two times. I want it to look something like this:

```
Name    V1  V2      V3      V4
User1   a   time1   time1   time2   
User1   a   time2   time1   time2
User1   b   time3   time3   time4
User1   b   time4   time3   time4
User2   c   time5   time5   time6
User2   c   time6   time5   time6
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, @Gen LG, did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

The basic idea is to get every other row with `seq(..., by = 2)`. Then replicate the values within the target row with `rep(..., each = 2)`.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  name = c("user1", "user1", "user1", "user1", "user2", "user2"),
  v1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
  v2 = c("time1", "time2", "time3", "time4", "time5", "time6"))

dat$v3 <- rep(dat[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(dat), by = 2),"v2"], each = 2)
dat$v4 <- rep(dat[seq(from = 2, to = nrow(dat), by = 2),"v2"], each = 2)

dat
#>    name v1    v2    v3    v4
#> 1 user1  a time1 time1 time2
#> 2 user1  a time2 time1 time2
#> 3 user1  b time3 time3 time4
#> 4 user1  b time4 time3 time4
#> 5 user2  c time5 time5 time6
#> 6 user2  c time6 time5 time6
```